# A class loaded with ClassLoader don't have access to changed variables

Tags: java, methods, jar, classloader, invocation

I have a problem:
There is a class compiled from external .java file

```java
    private static Class<?> LoadedClass;
    private static Object LoadedClassInstance;
    public static Method LoadedMethod;

[SKIP]

   private static Path compileSource(Path javaFile) {
        JavaCompiler compiler = ToolProvider.getSystemJavaCompiler();
        compiler.run(null, null, null, javaFile.toFile().getAbsolutePath());
        return javaFile.getParent().resolve("LoadedClass.class");
    }

    private static void runClass(Path javaClass)
            throws MalformedURLException, ClassNotFoundException, IllegalAccessException, InstantiationException, IllegalArgumentException, InvocationTargetException, NoSuchMethodException, SecurityException {
        URL classUrl = javaClass.getParent().toFile().toURI().toURL();
        URLClassLoader classLoader = URLClassLoader.newInstance(new URL[]{classUrl});
        LoadedClass = Class.forName("LoadedClass", true, classLoader);
```

in this class there is a method:

```java
        LoadedClassInstance = LoadedClass.getDeclaredConstructor().newInstance(); 
        LoadedMethod = LoadedClass.getDeclaredMethod("DoTheMethod");                
    }
```

Here is a static method to invoke loaded method:

```java
    public static void CallLoadedMethod() throws IllegalAccessException, IllegalArgumentException, InvocationTargetException {
        LoadedMethod.invoke(LoadedClassInstance);   
    }
```

Loaded method calls the other method:

```java
    import MyApp.MyClass1;
[SKIP]
    public static void DoTheMethod() {
        System.out.println("Your number is : "+MyClass1.Number);    
    }
```

I have two more classes to interract with:

```java
// MyClass1
    public static int Number = 5;
  public class MyClass1 {
    // DoSomeStuff
  }

// MyClass2
  public class MyClass2 {
    public static void SetTheNumberTo(int number){
        MyClass1.Number = number;
        System.out.println("Your NEW number is : "+MyClass1.Number);
    }
  }
```

Here is Loaded method invoke example:

```java
    MyClass2.SetTheNumberTo(10);
    Class_Loader.DoTheMethod();
```

When i run my app through Eclipse i get:

> Your NEW number is : 10
>
> Your number is : 10

But when i compile it to runnable .jar i get the other result :

> Your NEW number is : 10
>
> Your number is : 5

And here is the question: what am i doing wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Two class objects are the same if they have both the same name and the same ClassLoader.  You have loaded *two different classes* which each are named `MyClass1`.

`MyClass1.Number` in your `Class_Loader` is different from `MyClass1.Number` invoked from MyClass2 in your main program’s ClassLoader.  They are not the same field because they are not in the same class.

Comment: So, what i can do ot fix that problem? And why when i run it via Eclipse everything works like intended?

Comment: I suspect Eclipse has its own ClassLoaders in its Java runtime, which resolve classes differently.  As for fixing it, you can try [creating a ClassLoader with an explicit parent](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/13/docs/api/java.base/java/net/URLClassLoader.html#newInstance%28java.net.URL[],java.lang.ClassLoader%29), where that parent is `MyClass2.class.getClassLoader()`.

Comment: Tryed `URLClassLoader classLoader = URLClassLoader.newInstance(new URL[]{classUrl}, MyClass2.class.getClassLoader());` and that helps. But `System.out.println(MyClass2.class.getClassLoader().toString());` gives `java.net.URLClassLoader@2812cbfa` and `System.out.println(LoadedClass.class.getClassLoader().toString());` gives `java.net.FactoryURLClassLoader@7a95b7d3`. Wich looks different.